# How often can I type exit without logging out?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I logged in to Debian 7 via SSH, not as `root`. When writing `sudo` all the time became too much overhead, I did `sudo su`. Since the Debian default shell (`dash` ?) does not support the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to complete filenames, I ran `/bin/bash`. I added a few aliases to `.bash_aliases` and to activate them, I ran `/bin/bash` again (potentially a few more times) until I got all aliases right.

After doing some more system setup, I could not remember any more how many times I have to type `exit` to get back to the beginning but not logging out from SSH.

Actually this is not a big deal, since I could log in via SSH again, so this is more an academic question. I wondered if there is a way to find out

1. what exactly `exit` will exit, so I could at least check each time before I type it
2. how many times I can `exit` until the user is logged out completely

I tried `man exit` but it seems there is no manual available. `help exit` doesn't tell much either.

I first thought I could find a possible solution using `pstree`, but IMHO it lists `sshd` too often and `sudo su` is missing.

```
:~$ pstree | grep ssh
     |-sshd---sshd---sshd---sh---bash---bash-+-grep
```

Comment: `exit` is a shell builtin. So `man exit` will not work, as there is no man page for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SHLVL` variable to determine how far nested in you're, to a shell started by a login process:

```
$ echo $SHLVL 
1
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL 
2
$ bash
$ echo $SHLVL 
3
$ sudo su -            # Start a login shell, clears $SHLVL
# echo $SHLVL 
1
# logout
$ sudo su
# echo $SHLVL 
4
# bash
# echo $SHLVL 
5
```

Since the login shell from `su -` clears `SHLVL`, it has `SHLVL=1`. To quit the nearest such login shell in the shell ancestry, you have to use `exit` `$SHLVL` times.

---

`SHLVL` is not supported by `dash`, so whenever it enters the picture, the figure will be wrong. However, `dash` isn't the login shell for any usable account on Ubuntu, and `SHLVL` works on more advanced shells like `bash` and `zsh`.

---

I cannot reproduce your missing `sudo su`:

```
$ pstree -ps $$
init(1)───sshd(1404)───sshd(12614)───sshd(12673)───zsh(12674)───sudo(31012)───su(31014)───bash(31016)───pstree(31084)
```

Comment: To add to what @muru had to say, this will also count `screen` sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the command `ps` with no arguments. Here I have 3 nested bashes so 3 exits to type:

```
~ $ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1986 pts/2    00:00:10 bash
31351 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
31399 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
31450 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: What about `sudo su`? And what if my `ps` list is very long?

Comment: sudo and su both appear. You need to ignore the sudo in the count though.