# How to check if script was executed via command line or double-clicked?

Tags: command-line, scripts

How can I determine if a script was invoked from a command line or via double-click in file manager (Nautilis)?

If the former, I still have a command prompt when the script finishes, but if it was double-clicked (or executed via a .desktop file), the script executes in a window and then disappears. I want the window to remain open with a command prompt.

I figure the script could make this check and either do nothing - if invoked from a command line - or `exec` bash at the end if invoked via double-click or .desktop.

Haven't been successful using methods to check if interactive or not or tty.

Comment: Have your `.desktop` file call your script in a command terminal and execute it.  The first answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/437030/231142)  with the line `Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'echo hello;$SHELL'"` worked well when I tested it on my system.  I changed the `echo hello` to my own script.

Comment: Note to future viewers, while the accepted answer by muru worked, the method in the comment by @Terrance is what I ultimately used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if the parent process is the shell. For example:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $(readlink -f /proc/$(ps -o ppid:1= -p $$)/exe) != $(readlink -f "$SHELL") ]]
then 
    echo "Starting the shell..."
    exec "$SHELL"
else
    echo "Not starting a shell."
fi
```

`ps -o ppid:1= -p $$` prints the PID of the parent process (`ppid`) of the current process (`-p $$`). A `readlink` on `/proc/<pid>/exe` should print the path to the executable, which would be the shell if you ran it in a shell, or something else otherwise.

---

Another possibility is [the `SHLVL` variable](https://askubuntu.com/a/638646/158442), which indicates how nested the current the shell instance is. If run within a shell, the script should have `SHLVL` 2 or greater. When run by double clicking, or from a desktop launcher, it should be 1:

```
#! /bin/bash

if (( SHLVL > 1 ))
then 
    echo "Starting the shell..."
    exec "$SHELL"
else
    echo "Not starting a shell."
fi
```

Comment: The SHLVL option doesn't work for /bin/sh (dash) but the first option seems to work for both dash and bash.

Comment: @tcashin well, nobody uses `dash` as their interactive shell, and the question itself is tagged `bash`.

Comment: +1 for SHLVL as a platform-independent bash solution

Comment: Couldn’t the `SHLVL` also start with a value greater than 1 (in a file manager)? According to [this RIP Tutorial article](https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/16882/-shlvl) it’s not that platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the shell script was run on a terminal by analyzing the output of **tty** command.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $(tty) =~ "not a tty" ]]
then
    echo "Not running on terminal"

else
    echo "Running on terminal"
fi
```

Comment: That test can be simplified with `-t 0` instead of `$(tty) =~ ...`, IIRC.

Comment: The `-t 0` doesn't seem to work on `/bin/sh` or on my Ubuntu system.

Comment: @JamesWard. Are you sure. Did you try this command. `[ -t 0 ] && echo "Terminal" || echo "Not a Terminal"`

Comment: I guess it depends on what shell `/bin/sh` points to.  On my system it was `/bin/csh` which says `[: No match.`
The script does point out that `bash` is used.

Answer (score 0):

When double clicked from Nautilus you won't have the entire environment setup like you do in a regular terminal session. I use this boilerplate code to prevent crashes: [Desktop shortcut to Bash script crashes and burns](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019464/desktop-shortcut-to-bash-script-crashes-and-burns) . You can adapt it to your needs:

```
# $TERM variable may be missing when called via desktop shortcut
CurrentTERM=$(env | grep TERM)
if [[ $CurrentTERM == "" ]] ; then
    notify-send --urgency=critical "$0 cannot be run from GUI without TERM environment variable."
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I checked the differences between the environment when running a script from the terminal and the environment when running a script by double-clicking it in Files;

When you run a script by double clicking in Files the `$VTE_VERSION` variable is unset, so you can hook to it to decide whether to replace the current Bash instance with an interactive one or not.

That is, just put this at the end of your script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# ...
[ ! -z $VTE_VERSION ] && exec bash
```

To make this work also in case the script is run from a desktop file, change the desktop file's Exec= line from say:

```bsh
Exec=/path/to/script
```

To:

```bsh
Exec=sh -c '/path/to/script; exec bash'
```

This way `/path/to/script` will be executed and `sh` will be replaced by Bash upon `/path/to/script`'s completion.