# Close terminal for multiple users

Tags: command-line, root, logout

Let's suppose I run the terminal as `<username>`.
Then I switch to `root`:

`su - root`

and then back to the `<username>`.

So I was wondering if there's some option (or some other command) for `exit` to close the console for all these sessions, 'cause when i run `exit` at that point, it takes me back to `root` and then to my `<username>` again.

Comment: Just close the terminal tab. Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/638636/158442

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running, `su - root`, you could use the `exec` shell builtin:

```
exec su - root
```

This **replaces** the shell being run by `<username>` with the root login shell so that the parent process of root shell is the terminal emulator – not the original shell run by `username`. This means that when you exit the root shell, the terminal emulator should close the window or tab.